# PowerCli getting Storage I/O control status

Tags: powercli, esx

I'm trying to use powercli to return whether or not a datastore on a esxhost has got Storage I/O Control enabled.

I've been using `GetView -viewtype Datastore -Filter @{"Name"="DS_NAME"}` however I cant seem to dig out the piece of information I require from the result.

Any powerCli pro's out there than can help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result of your `Get-View` command is in `$vol` then you are looking for `$vol.IormConfiguration.Enabled`.

The [Datastore](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc/Datastore.html) objects returned by `Get-Datastore` also include a boolean property called *StorageIOControlEnabled*. `Get-VIObjectByVIView` will convert the results of your `Get-View` into those Datastore objects.

[Maybe](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.Datastore.html) datastores with no VMFS volumes behave differently, not sure.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks for your help!